# Редактор карт для игры Tiled Map как поменять координату У?

Tags: java, разработка-игр, libgdx

Как поменять высоту Y что бы снизу отображалось координата по нулю ??? что бы х и у были снизу равны нулям? координата х так и так нулевая будет, а вот у не дает мне покоя она почему то ведет отсчет сверху! мне нужно что бы отсчет был снизу.... Прошу помочь в решении данной проблемы! выкладываю скриншоты для наглядности...
[image: two muppets]
[image: two muppets]

Comment: на компе принято отсчёт вести с левого верхнего угла. Вы конечно можете вывернуть ось Y но чем вам мешает так?

Comment: Без проблем можно инвертировать ось так: y' = screenHeight - y;

Comment: дело в том что я уже начал писать код .. а добавив в эту программу объект он оказывается где то вверху . представьте что этих объектов  наделаю кучу в этой программе? я же не буду каждый раз высчитывать координату У для каждого объекта.. это кошмар будет

Comment: @Nofate а как вывернуть ось У в этой программе???

Comment: @AndreyKonstantinovich поэтому надо смириться с фактом, что 0,0 экрана вверху слева и работать с этим... ибо дальше только с этим и будете сталкиваться, и никто не даст в компани писать такие костыли... разве что в юнити есть там в canvas, кажется, отсчет внизу слева начинается

Comment: @АлексейШиманский дело в том что я использую библиотеку Libgdx там заливаю эту карту.. игрока помещаю на эту карту по коордианатам 20, 20 и там же все работает нормально.. отсчет слева снизу... а вот попытался создать объект в этой программе Tiled Map выходит что объект по оси У находится вверху! я же не буду каждому объекту указывать где он должен находится!!!! я уверен что с картой что то не то! как поменять ось У в этой программе кто может подсказать???

Comment: @AndreyKonstantinovich у `Libgdx`, как и у различных программ, фреймворков и прочих вещей наверняка есть встроенные функции/методы для конвертирования из одной системы в другую. Поэтому скорее лучше посмотреть у неё что и как.... посмотреть инструкции у неё https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Coordinate-systems или попробовать глянуть куда-то сюда: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/63492/  ..... я не вчитывался, но что-то тут есть вроде: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Tile-maps

Comment: @АлексейШиманский спасибо, но это не то что мне нужно.